# Difference between CSV in Excel and CSV in OpenOffice.org

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, openoffice-calc

There are different implementations of Comma Separated Values; two of them are Microsoft Excel and OpenOffice.

Is there any difference between these CSV implementations? For example both can open .csv extensions and both separate values with a comma. Are there any differences?

Comment: Please include the links and references you found on Google.

Comment: We need to stop using Excel for CSV files.  CSV files were intended for databases.  So lets use a database to manage them.  You'll find Access is 100 times better at handling CSV files.

Answer (score 4):

There should not be any difference. It's kind of standard file format. See wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 1):

They do support slightly different characters in the place of the comma, but these cases are very unusual in real life. This support is on the Import side. Both *generate* very standard CSV files, with commas for delimiters and quoted strings. The importer supports things like tab-delimited-files and files delimited with characters that aren't either tab or comma.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "comma" is not the separator used in Europe, as the "," is the ISO standard for decimal separation.  So CSVs are not really portable outside the US region.  [There was another SuperUser question on this](https://superuser.com/questions/180964/how-to-open-semicolon-delimited-csv-files-in-us-version-of-excel)

Answer (score 0):

There isnt' an "exact" difference. Both allow for some leighway in the format. You can specifiy your dellimiters, string closures, and whatnot in both programs.

CSV (Can be loaded in either):

```
3,2,'c',6
1,33,4,'h'
```

TSV (Tab-Seperated, works in the CSV Implementation):

```
1     3     5     7
7     "asd" 6     3
```

CSV really is simple enough, both programs can load a whole slew of variants.

If you really wanna see the differences in the **DEFAULT** approach, why dont you make sheets in both and save them as .csv ?