# Converting a .txt file with tab as separators into a excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have lines of data in a text file where each entry is separated by tab. I want them in different columns and each line to form a separate row in Excel.

I tried using `Data > Import` but it all comes in on single column. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: have you tried to replace tabs with commas and then import, i think `.csv` files are built that way, you can find & replace with **ctrl+h** in `notepad`

Comment: I've just tested tab separated import and it works just fine. Could you provide data sample perhaps?

Comment: Is it actually a 'tab' character or single spaces separating the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to open CSV with commas in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel)

Answer (score 5):

Select all of the data, paste into excel and then use the 'text import wizard' from the dropdown. Use the 'delimited' data type with tab separators and you should be set.

Also please add full information in future questions (version of excel, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Go to the **Data** tab and select **text to columns** under *data tools*
then select **delimited** and hit *next*. Then select **Tab** [or] **Space**<sup>1</sup> as the delimiter and hit *finish*

[image]

<sup>1</sup>You may need to check *treat consecutive delimiters as one*

<sub>brought to you in part by [our sponsors](https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel/407085#407085)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, Excel will ask when you open a specific file to specify the column delimiter if you OPEN the file as a .txt or .csv file.