# Advanced 'text to columns' in Excel - is there an add-in/macro available anywhere?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Often I need to split text which has multiple differing delimiters or other difficulties that the default 'text to columns' tool cannot handle e.g. ignore the first x columns

Is there a tool/app/addin for excel that can allow complex imports or 'text to columns' formatting?

Comment: I suggest you edit your post - questions asking for product recommendations or tools are [off topic here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). You can probably do this VBa but, the question is very vague (I assume it has to be) - it will be hard to add any logic if there is no consistency about what you want to split... Can you [edit your post](http://superuser.com/questions/847457/advanced-text-to-columns-in-excel-is-there-an-add-in-macro-available-anywher#) and provide some examples of the types of string you want to split?

Comment: If it is multiple records of consistent format, you could try to import it as a data file.  That includes a lot of flexibility in parsing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to open CSV with commas in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel)

Comment: It's not a duplicate - where in that question does it state how to deal with multiple different delimiters at the same time?

Comment: Both the Text Import Wizard and the Data ► Text to Columns command have the ability to skip any or all columns. Third dialog page, Column data format, Do not import column (skip).