# csv file formatting issue in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, csv

I have a csv file when opened in notepad looks like this:

```
sep=,
ProgramXX, PXXXXX, ....
IDXXXXX, XYZXXXXX, ....
```

This should open well formatted as csv file in excel program but what I see is this:
[image]

This problem is too localized to a 'client machine', not able to reproduce the issue elsewhere. Is there any settings that I'm missing in excel? The version of MS Excel is 2007.

Comment: why downvote? reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to https://superuser.com/users/166431/michael-field via [Easiest way to open CSV with commas in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel), the client needs to uncheck 'Use system separators' in their Excel advanced options for the 'sep=,' command to work.