# MySQL csv excel greek characters

Tags: mysql, csv, encoding, utf-8, greek

I developed an application using Bottle web framework and Python, to import some data into MySQL database. Most of the data where in Greek characters. On my application side, i didn't any further encoding/decoding on input data.

Accessing my DB using the CLI and a simple select query, i get something like this :

```
|  1 | ?????????  | ???????   |
```

When i browse my DB using the Sequel Pro application, i can read the characters regularly.

Using Sequel Pro, i can export the data into CSV and/or JSON.

Opening the output files using sublime Text, i get :

```
\u0394\u03b7\u03bc\u03ae\u03c4\u03c1\u03b9\u03bf\u03c2
```

from the JSON file.
and

> Δημήτριος

From the CSV file.

When i open the same (CSV) file on Excel (for MAC), i get something like this :

> Î”Î·Î¼Î®Ï„ÏÎ¹Î¿Ï

Any ideas how can i export the data, in a format that i can simply deliver to my colleagues without giving them too complicated details on how to open the file ?

Comment: What format is the csv? It's not exported as ms-dos csv or anything like that, right? Try [importing](http://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel/407085#407085) the csv, but choose UTF8 encoding, or whatever is applicable.

Comment: I have tried to import it selecting every single one available encoding.

Comment: just to rename the file ?

Comment: Using the Sequel Pro, i export it into 2 formats -> CSV and JSON, i can open both of them using text editor, the ".txt" is just an extension. Text editors cannot reformat the structure of the data. The csv, is just a txt file that uses "," as a delimiter for the columns, and new line for the lines.

Comment: I got mixed up by your sequence. The CSV displays properly in a text editor but not excel? While the JSON doesn't display properly at all/

Comment: I explained that on my question. CSV on sublime ->\u0394\u03b7\u03bc\u03ae\u03c4\u03c1\u03b9\u03bf\u03c2 * JSON on sublime - Δημήτριος * CSV on excel - Î”Î·Î¼Î®Ï„ÏÎ¹Î¿Ï.

Comment: That's the opposite of how your question reads.