# Excel converts comma delimited to tab delimited when saving

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, csv

I create data in Excel 2013 and save it as `.csv`. We have an application that imports files of type `.address` so after saving the file as `customer.csv`, I change the extension to `customer.address`. This is a custom file format specific to us, but essentially this is just CSV.

When I want to edit this `customer.address` file, I open this in Excel by selecting the

1. Delimited option
2. Select Comma in Delimiters
3. Finish

I edit my changes and when I press Save, this is the default dialog box that pops-up.

[image]

When I click `Yes`, it saves my file as `Tab delimited` not `Comma delimited`.

What I'm actually expecting is this, to preserve the commas.

[image]

How do I make this work such that when I save, the default option should be CSV (Comma delimited)?

Comment: Check your global settings on your OS

Comment: @Raystafarian how do I do that?

Comment: Depends on your OS

Comment: @Raystafarian can you please elaborate how I can do that? my OS is Windows 10 x64

Comment: Instead of clicking Save, click on Save As and choose the .CSV file type. Save As can be added to the Quick Access toolbar simply.

Comment: @OldUgly If I click Save As, it will save to another file. I would like to save the changes to the file I opened, in this case the `customer.address` file

Comment: @Raystafarian unfortunately the solution from the link above doesn't work. it does work if you have `.xlsx` or `.csv`. But for my case, I have `.address` which Excel doesn't recognize and it chooses to save it as tab delimited by default. I'd like to know how to default this to CSV

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel/407085#407085 is about the best you can do