# commas as text in CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

How can i get this entire string to be imported into excel from CSV as one column (read the comma as text in the string, not a separator)?

`=HYPERLINK("https://elicense.ct.gov/Lookup/ViewPublicLookupDocument.aspx?DocumentIdnt=1739916&GUID=0ECA04D1-1E18-4144-B5D2-3DF397D7CD60","Click to View")`

Comment: Set the delimiter as some unused character when you import.

Comment: thanks. except there are also commas as delimiters. and i'm trying to automate the process so the enduser who opens the CSV in excel doesn't have to alter any settings. i saw other posts that said to put the comma in quotes, or even double quotes, but nothing seems to help - the comma still breaks the string into two columns

Comment: I don't think it's possible to set `,` as a global delimeter and override it for  just one "field".

Comment: For a global override add `sep={some_character)` as the first line of the csv file, for example `sep=|`. You still have to uncheck Use system separators in Options>Advanced though.

Comment: See [Easiest way to open CSV with commas in Excel](http://superuser.com/a/730509)

Answer (score 1):

If your users are technical enough to use the Text Import Wizard, the other answers are better for you. But if you want to produce a CSV file that can be opened without any special user interaction then read on...

It depends whether you want the user to open the CSV in Excel and see a cell with the text `Click to View`, which is clickable and opens the supplied hyperlink, or whether you want the user to actually see the text

```
=HYPERLINK("https://elicense.ct.gov/Lookup/ViewPublicLookupDocument.aspx?DocumentIdnt=1739916&GUID=0ECA04D1-1E18-4144-B5D2-3DF397D7CD60","Click to View")
```

The two options are shown in the following CSV file:

```
Quoted text,"=HYPERLINK(""https://elicense.ct.gov/Lookup/ViewPublicLookupDocument.aspx?DocumentIdnt=1739916&GUID=0ECA04D1-1E18-4144-B5D2-3DF397D7CD60"",""Click to View"")"
Quoted formula,"=""=HYPERLINK(""""https://elicense.ct.gov/Lookup/ViewPublicLookupDocument.aspx?DocumentIdnt=1739916&GUID=0ECA04D1-1E18-4144-B5D2-3DF397D7CD60"""",""""Click to View"""")"""
```

When opened in Excel you will see:

[image: CSV viewed in Excel]

The *Quoted text* option is achieved by replacing all " characters with "", and then surrounding the whole string with " at beginning and end. This is just the standard technique for quoting in any CSV file.

The *Quoted formula* option is achieved by replacing all " characters with """" (4 quotes), and then prepending with "="" and suffixing with """ (3 quotes)

This *Quoted formula* monstrosity forces Excel to consider the contents of the CSV field to be a formula, with the value equal to the string you want it to be.  To achieve that, you first construct the formula to be:

```
="=HYPERLINK(""https://elicense.ct.gov/Lookup/ViewPublicLookupDocument.aspx?DocumentIdnt=1739916&GUID=0ECA04D1-1E18-4144-B5D2-3DF397D7CD60"",""Click to View"")"
```

And then you have to turn this into a legal CSV field by doubling all quotes, and surrounding with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Values that contain commas must be wrapped in double quotes for comma separated processing. Look at the following CSV sample and how it resolves in the import Wizard in Excel.

```
one,two,three
Text one, "Text two, has comma", Text three
```

[image]