# Problems sharing .xls spreadsheet via WhatsApp

Tags: android, ios, whatsapp, xls

I've saved a spreadsheet in the old format `.xls` on my MacBook and shared it via WhatsApp. Some of the recipients have informed me that the file is not usable both by Android and iPhone smartphones.
Could anybody help?

Comment: Is it uploaded correctly? Download it yourself and check if the file is intact.

Comment: Do they have an app installed to open these files?

Comment: Biswapriyo I have tried with my iPhone 5S, but it doesn't open it. Nevertheless, it works fine on my 
macBook.

Comment: davidbaumann, I don't know for sure. But they can open the same file in the most recent version .xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

Mac uses another way to store .xls files. Try to store it as a .csv file and see if that works.
Go to **File > Save As** and select "CSV (Comma delimited)" in the dropdown menu.
Make sure that the ones who are receiving the spreadsheet open it in the right way.

[Another post](https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel) has been made that explains how to open it correctly.
After opening it in Excel, you have to go the **Data** tab and select **text to columns**. here, select **delimited** and hit next. Then select **comma** as the delimiter and hit finish.

If this answer has helped you, you can accept this as the best answer.