# Excel How to make Text Qualifier editable or add a new entry in the existing list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, import, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a CSV file which is not properly formatted because one of the columns contains HTML code which use the same character as the Text Qualifier: the double quote.

Example:

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"01","text","<html><tag attrib="true">"
```

I decided to use another character as text qualifier, the backtick ` which is never present in my original file.

My data are like this now:

```
`col1`,`col2`,`col3`
`01`,`text`,`<html><tag attrib="true">`
```

Now my CSV is totally valid, but in Excel (2013) I cannot just change the Text Qualifier, it allows me only `"`, `'` or `{none}`

Is there any way to edit this list to add a new text qualifier?

I finally found another way to import it but I am just wondering why the `Text Qualifier` box is not editable.

Comment: What do you mean? When you import text to columns you can specify the delimiter.

Comment: @Raystafarian I have no problem with delimiter (between columns) it is the text qualifier I cannot change (only the three values mentioned)

Comment: Why not change it to text and use the text import? Or is that what you did already? I don't know of a way to change the default 3 options for text qualifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the qualifiers list.  However, you can escape quotes by doubling them.  Like so:

```
"01","text","<html><tag attrib=""true"">"
```

This will import correctly into Excel:

[image]

Even if you cannot manipulate the CSV more than changing the qualifier, you could do a mass find-replace on your existing CSV in notepad to get it to import correctly:

1. Create the CSV with backtick text qualifiers as you have already done.
2. Find-Replace all double quotes with double double quotes.
3. Find-Replace all backticks with double quotes.
4. Open with Excel.

Comment: In fact I made something very similar because the html attributes separator (name="value") can be single quote as well (my preferred way: name='value') then for me it is more a workaround than a Excel solution.

Comment: I read as well [this post](http://superuser.com/a/420025/68986) mentionning the sep=, in the first line of the CSV and I was thinking to get a similar code for the Text Qualifier but did not find anything on Internet.

Comment: Accepted as this workaround seems to be the best alternative.